# apache camel : cxf [4.0.0 -> 4.4.0] setHeader(xxx").xpath("exp",String.class,headerName) dont work..but not deprecated indication

Tags: camel-cxf

i use Quarkus 3.4.2 with Camel 4.0.0, and combo :
setHeader(xxx").xpath("exp",String.class,headerName)     works.
But into Quarkus 3.8.2 with camel 4.4.0   not works ...but not deprecated information... ?